# PMX crossover implementation in Clojure

Tags: beginner, clojure, genetic-algorithm

I'm starting to learn Clojure and as an exercise I've implemented the following functions (written in Java) in Clojure:

```
private int[] SwapValues(int val1, int val2, int[] array) {
    int[] result = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == val1) {
            result[i] = val2;
        } else if(array[i] == val2) {
            result[i] = val1;
        } else {
            result[i] = array[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}


public int[][] PartialCross(int[] subject1, int[] subject2, final int begin, final int end) {
    int[][] result = new int[2][subject1.length];
    int[] child1 = subject1.clone();
    int[] child2 = subject2.clone();

    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        child1 = SwapValues(subject1[i], subject2[i], child1);
        child2 = SwapValues(subject1[i], subject2[i], child2);
    }

    result[0] = child1;
    result[1] = child2;

    return result;
}
```

My result is:

```
(def chromosone1 [5 8 1 7 6 4 9 3 2])
(def chromosone2 [5 3 2 6 1 8 7 4 9])

(defn extract [input i j]
  (filter #(not (nil? %1)) 
          (map-indexed #(if (and (>= %1 i) (< %1 j)) %2) input)))

(defn chrossover-swap [input i]
  (let [i1 (first i)
        i2 (last i)]
    (map #(cond
           (= %1 i1) i2
           (= %1 i2) i1
           :else %1) input)))

(defn crossover [input1 input2]
  (let [i1 (extract input1 3 5)
        i2 (extract input2 3 5)
        i3 (partition 2 (interleave i1 i2))]
    (loop [to-swap i3
           o1 input1
           o2 input2]
      (if (zero? (count to-swap))
        [o1 o2]
        (do
          (def i (first to-swap))
          (recur (rest to-swap) (chrossover-swap o1 i) (chrossover-swap o2 i)))))))

(print (crossover chromosone1 chromosone2))
```

The code works, but I may have made it more complicated than it needs to be. I'm a beginner in functional programming and would like to know if this could be written in a simpler or more efficient way.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Good job on your first post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks great!

```
(filter #(not (nil? %1)) ...)
```

Prefer `%` instead of `%1` for single arguments

Simpler to write as `(remove nil? ...)`

```
(map #(cond
       (= %1 i1) i2
       (= %1 i2) i1
       :else %1) input))
```

When you have map + function definition in one statement, consider creating a named function with a defn, or using a for expression:

```
(for [i input]
  (cond ...))
```

Never ever def inside a loop:

```
(do
  (def i (first to-swap))
```

def creates a global var http://clojure.org/vars

You want:

```
(let [i (first to-swap)]
  ...)
```

Consider using destructuring:

```
(loop [[i & more] i3
  ...
 (if i
   (recur more (swap o1 i) (swap o2 i))
   [o1 o2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to [@TimothyPratley's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/110596/43360):

Functional programming enables you to develop functions that express common computing patterns. Many (most?) such functions are in the standard Clojure core library. Two of these, `replace` and `reduce`, turn out to be helpful here:

- You can use [`replace`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/replace) to define `chrossover-swap`.
- The idiomatic way to express `crossover` is to use [`reduce`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/reduce/).

Before we do this, let's note that your `extract` function is just the [standard `subvec`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/latest/clj/clojure.core/subvec/), so it disappears.

So your code becomes ...

```
(defn chrossover-swap [input [i1 i2]]
  (replace {i1 i2, i2 i1} input))

(defn crossover [input1 input2]
  (let [i1 (subvec input1 3 5)
        i2 (subvec input2 3 5)
        i3 (map vector i1 i2)]
    (reduce
      (fn [[o1 o2] i] [(chrossover-swap o1 i) (chrossover-swap o2 i)])
      [input1 input2]
      i3)))
```

The `reduce` in the `crossover` function chews through the sequence `i3`, using each element to yield a new `[o1 o2]`. Its arguments are

- the function applied to `[o1 o2]` and sequence element `i` to yield the
  new `[o1 o2]`;
- `[input1 input2]` - the initial `[o1 o2]`;
- `i3`  - the sequence whose elements `reduce` feeds to the function in turn.

Note

- Your `loop` may well be faster than this `reduce`.
- `map` can take several sequence arguments, which are fed in parallel
  to the function. Thus `(map vector i1 i2)` is more direct than
  `(partition 2 (interleave i1 i2))`.

---

Having said this, you'd probably want to define `crossover` to accept the subrange indices as arguments. They won't always be 3 and 5, I suppose.

So we define

```
(defn crossover [input1 input2 [start end]]
  (let [i1 (subvec input1 start end)
        i2 (subvec input2 start end)
        i3 (map vector i1 i2)]
    (reduce
      (fn [[o1 o2] i] [(chrossover-swap o1 i) (chrossover-swap o2 i)])
      [input1 input2]
      i3)))
```

And call it thus:

```
(print (crossover chromosone1 chromosone2 [3 5]))
```

... to get the same effect as before.

Comment: Wow, this is great! It's almost half of the original code :). Thank you!